# MvvmCross: Exception when switching tabs

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

I am using fragments for tabs. I am getting the following error when switching tab

The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

The error is occurring in the function

```
public override void OnTabChanged(string tag)
{
    base.OnTabChanged(tag);           
}
```

I am posting this after reading up similar SO question (https://stackoverflow.com/q/24741915/1421015) which did not help. The general answer seems that we need to clear the parent's view. However it's been a year since I've done any mvvmx and any help will be greatly appreciated. This is the status of the code about a year ago and I would like to get it working. The view class is below and I'm using mvvmx v3.1.1 on android.

```
[Activity(Label = "Manage Articles")]
internal class ManageArticles
    : BaseTabsFragmentActivity<ManageArticlesViewModel>
{
    public ManageArticles() 
        : base(Resource.Layout.ManageArticles, Resource.Id.actualtabcontent)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        var set = this.CreateBindingSet<ManageArticles, ManageArticlesViewModel>();
        set.Bind(this).For(v => v.ChangeDisplay).To(vm => vm.DisplayChange);
        set.Apply();             
    }

    protected override void AddTabs(Bundle args)
    {
        AddTab<ManageArticlesListTab>("Tab1", "Listing", args, TabViewModel.ListVM);
        AddTab<ManageArticlesEditTab>("Tab2", "Editor", args, TabViewModel.SelectedVM);            
    }

    public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.managearticles, menu);
        return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    public override bool OnOptionsItemSelected(IMenuItem item)
    {
        switch (item.ItemId)
        {
            case Resource.Id.managearticles__save:
                // TODO
                return true;
        }

        return base.OnOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public override void OnTabChanged(string tag)
    {
        base.OnTabChanged(tag);           
    }

    public override void OnTabFragmentChanging(string tag, FragmentTransaction transaction)
    {
        base.OnTabFragmentChanging(tag, transaction);
    }


    private IDisposable _subscription;
    private IMvxInteraction<Display> _displayInteraction;
    public IMvxInteraction<Display> ChangeDisplay
    {
        get
        {                
            return _displayInteraction;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_subscription != null)
            {
                _subscription.Dispose();
                _subscription = null;
            }
            _displayInteraction = value;
            if (_displayInteraction != null)
            {
                _subscription = _displayInteraction.WeakSubscribe(DoDisplayChange);
            }
        }
    }


    private void DoDisplayChange(Display display)
    {
        var tabHost = FindViewById<TabHost>(Android.Resource.Id.TabHost);

        switch (display)
        {
            case Display.All:
                tabHost.SetCurrentTabByTag("Tab1");
                break;

            case Display.Selected:
                tabHost.SetCurrentTabByTag("Tab2");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `This is the status of the code about a year ago` - do you mean this code worked a year ago and now has stopped working? Or has this never worked? There is a sample of tabs fragments on https://github.com/MvvmCross/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Fragments/FragmentSample.UI.Droid/Views/TabView.cs - does this have the same issue? If not, then I think you will need to do more investigation and possibly to edit your question to provide more details about the problem in the code you are looking at.

Comment: Hi. No the code has never worked. I managed to create a tabbed activity based on the sample. The difference is that in this version, the tab page is being generated in the view instead of being inflated (generated means a bit like how Xam Forms does it).
Anyway I am now exploring Xamarin Forms. I had invested significant time in picking up Mvvx but anything related to fragments seems to require a lot of effort. Fragment is the way to go if we're using things like popup dialog and tab pages (in android).
Thanks for your Mvvx though, it proves that there was a better way of doing things!